# How do I prevent tomatoes from falling in a green salad?

Tags: tomatoes, salad

When making a green salad, I have taken to grating carrots instead of dicing them so they will mix better with the leaves.

I can't grate tomatoes. No matter how small I dice them (short of pureeing) they always precipitate out and fall to the bottom of the bowl.

How can I prepare the tomatoes or the salad to keep them mixed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I work around this by serving tomatoes on the top of the individual salads after they've been portioned out.  I'm not sure of a way to keep them incorporated.

Comment: That's what I do, too. That way you can also arrange everything nicely.

Answer (score 3):

Cut it into very thin slices? The thinner the better and then maybe you can get it to just lay flat on top of leaves?

Answer (score 2):

While I don't grate tomatoes, I cut them much smaller than salads I see in restaurants, or on TV commercials for salad dressing. Typically I will cut the tomato into 4 wedges, and if it's large, cut each wedge into 2 thinner ones, then lay the wedge down on the board and cut it into 6 or 8 pieces about the size of a pea. Careful not to dislodge or lose the jelly which has most of the flavour.

Also, don't make your lettuce pieces too small. And finally, don't feel that your salad should somehow stay emulsified no matter what you do. Toss it just before you serve it, and be prepared to mix things up a little while you are eating it.

Answer (score 2):

Try serving on a plate or shallower bowl, then nothing can fall to the bottom. You'll probably notice that it's rare to see salad served in a bowl at a restaurant.